# Finding version of multiple files in a folder C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on tool which is comparison between two folders.

Here's the test cases need to satisfy,

1. Have to check file names which are similar in both folders -- Done
2. The files having same name have to undergo version comparison -- Here is the problem

I can find the version of a file giving the path of single file and `name.exe`. But, I want to get all files version.

I don't want to give every path of single file and name.

Here is part of a code,

```
if (File.name == File1.Name)
{
    versioncheck(file.name); 
}

private void versioncheck(string Name)
{
    var versionInfo = FileversionInfo.GetversionInfo(@"C:\mainfolder\chrome.exe");  
    String version = versionInfo.FileVersion;
    Console.WriteLine("file version" + version);
}
```

This code giving single file check, but I want to get all files in a loop or something.

Is there any way?

Comment: You're passing in the path of the file to check, but you're ignoring that path and checking `C:\mainfolder\chrome.exe` instead. Plus, if you want to compare the versions of two files, surely you need to pass in the path of both?

Comment: Don't mind  the string I'm passing. Is there any way without giving path of every file and name to get the version details?

Comment: If you want to get the version of a file, you need the full path of the file. You can't just ask *"what's the version of the file"* and expect the system to guess which file you mean!